# Resummation of the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory, gamma-function, polygamma

Recently, I encountered the following series:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I} = \sum_{q=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma \left(q+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \left(2 q \psi
   ^{(0)}(q)-2 q \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(q+\frac{1}{2}\right)+1\right)}{\Gamma (q+1)^2}\, \ ,
\end{equation}
where $\psi^{(0)}$ represents the digamma function. By using numerical methods, I have determined that this series should converge to the following value:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I} = -1+\pi-\frac{\pi^2}{4}
\end{equation}
This result appears promising. I am curious if anyone knows whether this series has been analytically summed, or if there are suggestions for summing it analytically. Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks